# Function get_the_ID() doesn't return 404 and search pages

Tags: get-the-id

I have a large switch statement where I get all the pages using the function `get_the_ID()` but it doesn't work for 404 and search pages. This is my code:

```
global $page, $paged, $post;

$selectpage = get_the_ID();

switch ($selectpage) {
    case (is_single() || is_page()):
        break;

    //......

    case (is_category()):
        break;
    case (is_search()):
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I can use an if statement instead of a switch, but a switch doesn't re-evaluates the conditions. Also, I can use an if statement out of the switch, like this:

```
if ( is_404() ) {

} elseif ( is_search() ) {

} else {

    switch ($variable) {
        case ():
        break;

    }
}
```

But I prefer to think there's a better function for that situation, a function that includes the 404 and search pages.

Comment: `get_the_ID` returns the numeric ID of the current post in the loop. 404 pages have no ID, and any archive or search page will have as many IDs as there are posts in the main query.

Comment: See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/175228/31545). I have explained everything there :-). `get_the_ID()` simply returns the first post's ID in the loop on the page. 404 pages has no posts so the function will return 0.